# Pass data from post to Serializer

Tags: django, serialization

I have some data {iddepart, idarrivee} to use in serializer. This data is not present in data model but used internally to compute some fields:

Here is my code and I get error : The field 'iddepart' was declared on serializer ReservationSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

```
class TravelViewReserveSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                 mixins.ListModelMixin,
                 mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                 mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    Model = Travel
```

And serialiser :

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    #user = UserSerializer()
    #travel = TravelSerializer()

    iddepart = serializers.SerializerMethodField('iddepart')
    idarrivee = serializers.SerializerMethodField('idarrivee')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #code=  random_generator()        
        ##code = random_generator()

        reservation = Reservation(**validated_data)
        reservation.code = random_generator() 
        reservation.save()
        #iddepart =  validated_data['iddepart']
        #idarrivee = validated_data['idarrivee']

class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = ('id','reservedplaces','code','datecreation','travel','user')
```

Comment: How does your Meta options look for the `ReservationSerializer'?

Comment: I added Meta for serialize but as I said fields iddepart idarrivee doesn't existe in db and I would juste use them to compute some field

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    iddepart = validated_data.pop('iddepart','default value')
    idarrivee = validated_data.pop('idarrivee', 'default value')
    # do somthing with this data


    #code=  random_generator()
    ##code = random_generator()

    reservation = Reservation(**validated_data)
    reservation.code = random_generator()
    reservation.save()
    #iddepart =  validated_data['iddepart']
    #idarrivee = validated_data['idarrivee']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `iddepart` and `idarrivee` to fields option in the Meta.

Your Meta should look like this,

```
class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = ('id','reservedplaces','code','datecreation','travel','user',
             'iddepart','idarrivee')
```

Comment: Even if they aren't used in databse models ?

Comment: Yes. The fields option is to mention which all fields to include in the serializer either it is from Model field or a custom field.